# Windowsでのテキスト編集の時、文字を入れ替えたい

Tags: windows

「AはBである」といった文章を、「BはAである」といった風に、テキストを編集したいです。
いつもCut & Pasteを使って入れ替えるのですが、この操作がかなり頻繁にあるため、もし1コマンドで実行できるようなショートカット等あれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

インターネットで検索しましたが、良い記事が見つからなかったため、質問させていただきました。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: WindowsでとおっしゃってますがWindowsはOSなので実際はメモ帳等を利用しているということですか？それとも、利用しているツールは関係なくてメモ帳でもEdgeでもWordでもそういった類の変換をしたいということですか？

Comment: 特にアプリケーションを限定しているわけではなく、Windows全般について伺いたいです。しかし、Word内等だけで有効なショートカットがある場合でも、良ければそちらもお伺いしたいです。

Comment: 例えばVBAでそうした処理を作成して、かつVBAでそれに対するショートカットキーを登録すれば使えるでしょう。[【VBA入門】正規表現で文字列を抽出、置換する方法(RegExp)](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/33541), [MS Wordを利用した文字列の検索と置換](http://www.shuiren.org/chuden/teach/word/search/replace02.htm), [Word VBAで作成したマクロをショートカットキーに登録する方法](https://tonari-it.com/word-vba-macro-shortcut-key/)

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。需要がありそうで、かつ、実装も現実的な操作だと思ったのですが、ショートカットがデフォルトでWindowsのアプリ全般的に実装されているわけではないとの理解でよさそうですか？

Comment: アイデアとしては有りで、需要はあるかどうか判断はつきませんが、それを汎用的/標準的なOSの共通UIとして実装や操作することは今となっては非現実的ですね。ショートカットはもちろん無いですし、そうした処理をOSの共通なUIで行う機能は存在しません。そうしたものを実現するかどうかは個々のアプリケーションの設計や実装に委ねられています。

Comment: [AutoHotkey - The ultimate automation scripting language for Windows](https://www.autohotkey.com/) を使うことで実現できるかもしれません。例えば [Autohotkeyで句読点置換，改行除去](http://blog.ayakix.com/2010/09/autohotkey.html) などという事ができます。また、[プログラミング言語としての AutoHotKey](https://m-hiyama.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/07/16/124314) が参考になるかと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

残念ながら「AはBである」といった日本語表現を解析し、アプリケーションを限定せず、ワンアクションで置換処理を実行する機能はWindowsに存在しません。

しかしWindowsの標準機能であるPowershellと[「ショートカット」の「ショートカットキー」](https://www.724685.com/word/wd190925.htm)を組み合わせればちょっとしたRPAを実現できます。

1. 任意のフォルダに後述のPowershellスクリプトを保存します。
   スクリプトの作成方法や実行方法([.ps1ファイルの文字コード](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/1d5bf04b-9b0a-4188-9328-a9eca3d897e8/powershell124731246312522125031248865288ps112289psm652891239825991?forum=powershellja)や[Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1)など)の説明は省略します。
2. 保存したスクリプトをエクスプローラー上で右クリックして「ショートカットの作成(S)」をクリックします。
3. 作成したショートカットファイルをデスクトップに貼り付けます。
4. デスクトップのショートカットファイルを右クリックして「プロパティ(R)」をクリックします。
5. 「ショートカット」タブの`リンク先(T):`の先頭に`powershell` を追記します。
6. `ショートカットキー(K):`に任意のキーを入力します。
   [image: ショートカットのプロパティ]
7. OKボタンを押します。

これで1コマンドでコピー(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)→置換→貼り付け(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)を実行できるショートカットを作成しました。
※そのためxyzzyなど上記のショートカットキーを受け付けないソフトでは動作しません。

後は「BはAである」をカーソルで範囲選択してショートカットキーを押し、数秒待ちます。(powershellの起動を待つために時間がかかります)
下記のように動作します。一瞬黒い画面が出るのは仕様です。

[image: 動作イメージ]

**Powershellスクリプト**

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{TAB}")
Start-Sleep -m 100
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^c")
Start-Sleep -m 100
$src = Get-Clipboard
$m = [regex]::Match($src, "(.+)は(.+)である")
if($m.Success) {
    $res = "{0}は{1}である" -f $m.Groups[2], $m.Groups[1]
    $res | Set-Clipboard
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^v")
}
```